# Load word document in Java

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I have a Java project and it uses word files using JWord library.

How can I load my word files in the project without calling its absolute path, so when I open my project in another computer it'll read the files without error.

I'm using netbeans.

Comment: Is your question about retrieving file paths (you should check out a FileChooser) or parsing the contents of the Word document?

Comment: I have exist word files, but I want to load it so if I use anouther computer it'll work without error.

Comment: You can use a relative path.  You can make the path of the file command line argument.  You can get the pathname from a properties file.  You can get the pathname from the user via JChooser.  You can put the word file into your JAR file an open it as a resource rather than as a file.

Comment: @StephenC I use resource it worked well for me, thanks!